# Compiled length of validation rule functions

Tags: formula, validation-rule, performance

I have a validation rule that is around 3000 characters in length. It uses a the following functions (most of them quite a number of times): `IF`, `NOT`, `OR`, `AND`, `LEN`, `BEGINS`, `SUBSTITUTE`, `VALUE` and `MOD`. If I try to save the validation rule, I get the message that the maximum size of 4000 bytes is exceeded, it tells me my validation rule is 4252 bytes.

I know some functions are expanded, but it's like a black box to me. Is there a list of expansions somewhere so that I can figure out how to optimize my validation rule?

Comment: For SObject formula fields, a reference to another field that is a formula results in a copy of the formula being included so expanding the length. Perhaps the same pattern applies to validation rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for the documentation it can be found at [Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm). Also take a look at [Tips for Reducing Formula Size](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/16/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_formula_size_tipsheet.pdf)

---

The document describes many strategies for reducing compile size. One of the most common techniques that crops up on SFSE is to use `CASE` statements. This strategy comes in many common flavors, including reducing `IF` chains and `OR` whitelists.

**`IF` Chain**

Replace:

```
IF(Field__c = '<value_1>', 1,
    IF(Field__c = '<value_2>', 2)
)
```

With:

```
CASE(Field__c,
    '<value_1>', 1,
    '<value_1>', 2,
    null
)
```

**`OR` Whitelist**

Replace:

```
OR(
    ISPICKVAL(Field__c, '<value_1>'),
    ISPICKVAL(Field__c, '<value_2>')
)
```

With:

```
1 = CASE(Field__c, '<value_1>', 1, '<value_2>', 1, 0)
```

Comment: Good to know, but does not explain the 3000 character rule being expanded to 4252 characters.

Comment: I'll take a look at that document. I've got a lot of nested IFs, so this could be a solution.

Comment: This looks promising, I've changed one of many IF's to a CASE, and already it's gotten a lot smaller. I will resume this changing on monday and probably accept this answer by then!

Comment: @Lex It's not opaque, but basically your formulas get compiled to Oracle SQL, and that's what counts against you. Field references are *the most* expensive part of a formula; using any trick you can to reduce the number of field references is the most enabling factor. This is why CASE far outperforms IF, because the field is only referenced once. Also, standard fields are really cheap (~10 characters), but custom fields are expensive (>200 characters).

Comment: `CONTAINS('US:UK:FR:DE',CountryIsoCode)` is another good trick to validate value against predefined (limited) list of valid choices in a compact manner. `:` is used as assumed not to be in input - one could use `^` or `|` too.

Comment: I think you all should be posting this stuff as an answer. Nothing wrong with a few answers that work together in tandem!